# Recursive file looping based on extension

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I'm trying to recurse through directories, grab files ending with a specific extension and populate matching files into a text box. However, my loop doesn't seem to be executing. Here's what I came up with:

```
searchDir = D:\some_directory

^g:: CaptureLoop()

CaptureLoop(){
    Loop, Files, %searchDir%\*.xyz, R ; Recurse, get files with .xyz ext
    {
        MsgBox, loop ; Not reached
        SplitPath, %A_LoopFileLongPath%, file_name, dir, ext, name_no_ext, drive
        MsgBox, %name_no_ext% ; Populating this field is the goal.
    }
}
```

I'm certain that my search directory contains .xyz files. My platform is Windows 7.

**One possible solution**

For some reason AHK cannot see my strings unless they're inside the function. This doesn't seem to be the standard behavior though. If you have this issue, try moving the variables inside the function:

```
CaptureLoop(){
    searchDir = D:\some_directory
    Loop, Files, %searchDir%\*.xyz, R ; Recurse, get files with .xyz ext
    { ... }
```

Comment: Should work if you replace `%A_LoopFileLongPath%` with `A_LoopFileLongPath`. Variables in an [expression](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions) are not enclosed in percent signs.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I'm not even reaching SplitPath. I've tried your suggestion the statement above: `Loop, Files, searchDir \*.xyz, R` but this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: %searchDir% is OK.Try also to run the script as administrator.

Comment: No dice. I think this issue is in the variables of the loop statement. If I add a message box above it, `MsgBox,,, %searchDir%\*.xyz`, all I see is "\\*.xyz" in the box. Seems like `%searchDir%` isn't taking on a value?

Comment: Solution added above.

Comment: I don't think so. This way you can use the function in only one directory (the one you define inside the function). Your first code works on my system if I replace e.g. "D:\some_directory" with "C:\Windows" and "xyz" with "txt". And try the code in a stand alone script.

Comment: Hmm, that's definitely the behavior I would expect. However, I can't seem to coerce this script to work without the string literals within the function definition. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasons I can see, is that

- you define the variable "searchDir" outside the [auto-execute section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto)
  or
- your script need [administrator rights](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs) to work.

Try it this way as a stand-alone script:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

; If the script is not elevated, relaunch as administrator and kill current instance:

full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")

if not (A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)"))
{
    try ; leads to having the script re-launching itself as administrator
    {
        if A_IsCompiled
            Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%" /restart
        else
            Run *RunAs "%A_AhkPath%" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    }
    ExitApp
}

searchDir := "D:\some_directory"

        RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===

^g:: CaptureLoop()

CaptureLoop(){
    Loop, Files, %searchDir%\*.xyz, R ; Recurse, get files with .xyz ext
    {
        MsgBox, loop
        SplitPath, A_LoopFileLongPath, file_name, dir, ext, name_no_ext, drive
        MsgBox, %name_no_ext% ; Populating this field is the goal.
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the issue was with searchDir definition as you stated above. Thanks.